# "estar de obra" vs. "estar en obra"

Tags: gramática

¿Se puede decir "estar de obra" en vez de "estar en obra"?

La pregunta se basa en la siguiente oración que he encontrado en línea:

> Dispone de hospedería con pocas celdas y un restaurante (actualmente está en obras).

Comment: Busqué la frase exacta "está de obra" con google y encontré muchos ejemplos.  Fíjate que voté por cerrar la pregunta por falta de esfuerzo.

Comment: @walen - ¿Te parece igual el nivel de responsabilidad del que comenta, al del autor de la pregunta?  Por otra parte, ¿te parece bien planteada una pregunta que dice, "he encontrado la la siguiente oración en línea," pero que no da enlace?

Comment: @walen - ¿Nunca te has encontrado en una situación con dos motivos para votar a cerrar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ambas expresiones existen y se pueden usar, pero no significan exactamente lo mismo:

- "estar **en** obras" se aplica a objetos y estructuras: un edificio (como tu hotel), una carretera... Cuando decimos "el hotel está en obras" nos referimos a que el edificio está sufriendo reformas.
- "estar **de** obras" se aplica a personas y entidades: el dueño del edificio, los habitantes del pueblo por donde pasa la carretera... Cuando decimos "los del hotel están de obras" nos referimos a que las personas que hay en el hotel están inmersas en un proceso de reformas.
  En este último caso podría llegar a personalizarse "hotel" y decir "el hotel está de obras", donde "hotel" se refiere a la empresa, a las personas que lo regentan, no al edificio como estructura.

Como ves, son dos enfoques distintos para comentar la misma situación.

También existe, con significado propio, la locución "[de obra](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QnrhaT6#CHWF0As)", pero sus usos no cuadran<sup>1</sup> con el empleo del verbo "estar". Tampoco me consta que exista la expresión "estar de obra", con "obra" en singular y con significado distinto al que tiene en plural. Si existiera, se me ocurre que podría tener un significado similar a "está nuevo, recién construido" pero, como digo, no me consta.
Decir "el hotel está de obra" sería por tanto un uso equivalente al "estar de obras" que he mencionado antes.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Podría fabricarse un contexto en el que tendría sentido usar "de obra" en su segunda acepción como locución adverbial; por ejemplo: *"En esta nuestra primera Convención de Empresas de Hostelería y Turismo Rural, muchas grandes cadenas hoteleras se han apuntado solo de palabra, pero nuestro hotel está de obra."* Pero habría que ser muy retorcido para emplear una construcción así en un registro normal (aunque quizá sea el típico chiste de hotelero, a saber jajaja).</sub>

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!

Comment: Creo que la he marcado como "aceptada" ... Espero que lo haya hecho correctamente.